# What is the keyboard shortcut to go to the end of the file in vi?

Tags: linux, vi

I'm using putty to view a 30+MB file in vi on a Linux server, and I have to use PgDn to scroll to the bottom of the page. I realize I can use tail but I want to be able to move up and down the file with it open in vi. Is there not a way to go to end of file or top of file immediately using a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 3):

The key for the end of file is `G` (uppercase g).

See [vi cheat sheet](http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html), for example.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a simple `G` in normal mode. That is capital G, not g.

You can also open a file and directly go to the end of it using:

```
vim +$ thefile
```

Comment: And to get back to the beginning use `gg`.

Answer (score 1):

Type vimtutor or inside the editor :help